# What does an Aboleth's Legendary Action Detect do?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The [aboleth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/aboleth) is described as having a Legendary Action called Detect:
"Detect. The aboleth makes a Wisdom (Perception) check."

What does the Detect action of the Aboleth actually accomplish?

Comment: Ancient dragons also have a Legendary Detect action. I also have no idea what it's supposed to do.